# EmberJS Random Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I'm trying to create a route that will load a random instance of a model (lets call it Entry), **each** time the route is activated (ie, any time a `{{#linkTo "entries.random"}}link{{/linkTo}}` is clicked, on page refresh, etc).

I was able to make a route show a random entry by using `App.Entry.find(-1)`, and revising my RoR Entries controller to interpret `-1` as "random" - which is certainly not ideal. This approach also didn't make Ember reload the data each time a link is clicked.

Can anyone help me determine the proper way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `RandomRoute` defined where you then provide a random model returning it from the model `hook` e.g.

```
App.RandomRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Math.random();
  }
});
```

here is a working fiddle that shows the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/rCmxJ/13/

hope it helps

Comment: This is actually pretty great, and has me on the right path - thanks!

**However**, it has one issue that I need to overcome: I would like the `random` button in your fiddle to reload the model with a new random even when the route is the current route. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/rCmxJ/13/ you can use the `action` helper to trigger an event in your ApplicationRoute for example...

Comment: Wonderful - your suggestions set me on the right path, and helped me solve the problem! Thanks.